# How can I connect to InfluxDB in Airflow using the connections?

Tags: python, influxdb, airflow

I have seen that you can save and require different types of connections to different DBs but I cannot find the way of connecting to Influxdb.
[image]

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no influxdb connection available but influxdb works on http only, so you can create a http connection and use it for influxdb

Comment: Thx! Probably in the next few months... :) But is enough with your answer by now